# Order of execution of branching Promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Is there a spec on the order of execution of branches of a JavaScript Promise?

Consider this code:

```js
// Create a promise that will be resolved when we call the function `r`
let r;
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    r = resolve; // Store the resolver in `r`, so we can call it later.
});

// When `promise` resolves, print "I am the first branch".
promise.then(() => console.log("I am the first branch"));

// When `promise` resolves, also print "I am the second branch".
promise.then(() => console.log("I am the second branch"));


// Resolve `promise`
r();
```

The Promise `promise` is branched out into two branches.

From my testing, the first branch is executed before the second.

```
I am the first branch
I am the second branch
```

My question:
Is this guaranteed by the JavaScript spec, or am I relying on an undefined behavior?

Note:
I could, of course, chain the promises instead. Like this:

```js
promise.then(() => console.log("I am the first branch")).then(() => console.log("I am the second branch"));
```

But I would prefer to branch them if possible.

Comment: No, promises are not guaranteed to run in any particular order. If one promise relies on another then they should use a `then` or an `await`

Comment: You probably shouldn't rely on this extensively. If you need "second branch" to happen after "first branch" then chain the two. Your code works *here* but might not in other cases.

Comment: "*But I would prefer to branch them if possible.*" if they depend on each other, then they should not branch. It's as simple as that.

Comment: in this example, I think it is guaranteed, since you're adding 2 x `.then` to the same promise - but then, that may just be how my promise polyfill works - but if the two "branches" in turn use other promises then all bets are off

Comment: @liam for sure they are.

Comment: [27.2.5.4 `Promise.prototype.then`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise.prototype.then) -> 5. Return PerformPromiseThen -> [27.2.5.4.1 `PerformPromiseThen`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-performpromisethen) -> 9.a: _"If `promise.[[PromiseState]]` is pending, then **Append `fulfillReaction` as the last element of the List that is promise `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]`**"_

Comment: @Bravo in this example, there are no competing tasks to resolve. So I'd expect this to always resolve in the same order. But add some more tasks and it becomes unpredictable.

Comment: @Andreas would you mind putting that into an answer

Comment: @VLAZ - one can only answer what the question presents :p

Comment: Relying on the order because some arcane part of the spec happens to in this perticular circumstance at this time produce a side effect that means they run in order is asking for trouble in the future. The over-arching rule is don't rely on the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (-> calling `.then()` multiple times on the *same promise*)...

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000) });

p.then(() => console.log("first"));
p.then(() => console.log("second"));
```

...the order is guaranteed because `.then()` acts like a `.push()` with arrays. The relevant path from the specification is:

Step 5 in `Promise.prototype.then` + Step 9.a in `PerformPromiseThen`

> [27.2.5.4 `Promise.prototype.then ( onFulfilled, onRejected )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise.prototype.then)
>
> When the then method is called with arguments `onFulfilled` and
> `onRejected`, the following steps are taken:
>
> ```
> 1. Let promise be the this value.
> 2. If IsPromise(promise) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 3. Let C be ? SpeciesConstructor(promise, %Promise%).
> 4. Let resultCapability be ? NewPromiseCapability(C).
> 5. Return PerformPromiseThen(promise, onFulfilled, onRejected, resultCapability).
> ```

and then

> [27.2.5.4.1 `PerformPromiseThen ( promise, onFulfilled, onRejected [ , resultCapability ] )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-performpromisethen)
>
> The abstract operation `PerformPromiseThen` takes arguments promise,
> `onFulfilled`, and `onRejected` and optional argument `resultCapability` (a
> `PromiseCapability` Record). It performs the “`then`” operation on promise
> using `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` as its settlement actions. If
> `resultCapability` is passed, the result is stored by updating
> `resultCapability`'s promise. If it is not passed, then
> `PerformPromiseThen` is being called by a specification-internal
> operation where the result does not matter. It performs the following
> steps when called:
>
> ```
> 1. Assert: IsPromise(promise) is true.
> 2. If resultCapability is not present, then
>     a. Set resultCapability to undefined.
> 3. If IsCallable(onFulfilled) is false, then
>     a. Let onFulfilledJobCallback be empty.
> 4. Else,
>     a. Let onFulfilledJobCallback be HostMakeJobCallback(onFulfilled).
> 5. If IsCallable(onRejected) is false, then
>     a. Let onRejectedJobCallback be empty.
> 6. Else,
>     a. Let onRejectedJobCallback be HostMakeJobCallback(onRejected).
> 7. Let fulfillReaction be the PromiseReaction { [[Capability]]: resultCapability, [[Type]]: Fulfill, [[Handler]]: onFulfilledJobCallback }.
> 8. Let rejectReaction be the PromiseReaction { [[Capability]]: resultCapability, [[Type]]: Reject, [[Handler]]: onRejectedJobCallback }.
> 9. If promise.[[PromiseState]] is pending, then
>     a. Append fulfillReaction as the last element of the List that is promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]].
>     b. Append rejectReaction as the last element of the List that is promise.[[PromiseRejectReactions]].
> 10. Else if promise.[[PromiseState]] is fulfilled, then
>     a. Let value be promise.[[PromiseResult]].
>     b. Let fulfillJob be NewPromiseReactionJob(fulfillReaction, value).
>     c. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(fulfillJob.[[Job]], fulfillJob.[[Realm]]).
> 11. Else,
>     a. Assert: The value of promise.[[PromiseState]] is rejected.
>     b. Let reason be promise.[[PromiseResult]].
>     c. If promise.[[PromiseIsHandled]] is false, perform HostPromiseRejectionTracker(promise, "handle").
>     d. Let rejectJob be NewPromiseReactionJob(rejectReaction, reason).
>     e. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(rejectJob.[[Job]], rejectJob.[[Realm]]).
> 12. Set promise.[[PromiseIsHandled]] to true.
> 13. If resultCapability is undefined, then
>     a. Return undefined.
> 14. Else,
>     a. Return resultCapability.[[Promise]].
> ```

Comment: I think the important part here is **In this case**

Comment: @Liam Added a short explanation for _"this case"_ so the answer should work without the question

Comment: I don't really dispute this answer. But I do think relying on order or promises (in general) is a bad idea that shouldn't really be promoted.